# Do subdomains have a part in cross-browser restrictions when calling webservices from Javascript?

Tags: .net, jquery, web-services, subdomain

The scenario is this:

- My html page is on http://www.mydomain.com/somepage.html
- Using jQuery, I call a webservice on: http://subdomain.mydomain.com/webservice.asmx/somemethod

At the moment this is not working. I suspect that the subdomain is breaking a x-browser restriction. Any ideas?

It is working locally when the html page and the webservice are running off my localhost.

Cheers.

Comment: Is JSONP an option?  If it helps, you are correct in your suspicion, the `www.` is cross-domain restricted from `subdomain.`, the same way as `badsite.co.uk` is to `mybank.co.uk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), the host must match exactly (so must the protocol and port, but that's an aside).  If a matching *suffix* could suffice, `foo.com` would be deemed the "same origin" as `bar.com`, or `fie.co.uk` the same as `flap.co.uk`, etc, completely destroying the purpose of the policy.

I realize you think of `www.blah.com` as "more related" to `whatever.blah.com` than the examples I gave, but that's simply not the case - think of all the myriads of `something.appspot.com` domains running Google App Engine apps from myriads of different authors with absolutely no relationship among them, for example.

Comment: I think the user understands this concept...I don't believe comprehension is the issue, he's simply looking for a viable work-around to it.

Comment: Or think about any .co.uk or .com.au adress.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a JSONP service, or use .NET as a proxy?

Otherwise you are not conforming to same origin policy.